# DIY Chromebook debug cable (SuzyQable / Suzy Q Cable)

Tags: usb, serial, cables

I'm trying to build a Suzy Q Cable to debug a Chromebook, but I can't get it working.

The instructions are [here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/third_party/hdctools/+/master/docs/ccd.md#making-your-own-suzyq).

What I have tried:

- Opened the CCD state with the gsctool (the device supports Suzy Q debugging).
- Swapped D+ and D-.
- Re-soldered the breakout board with different USB A cables.

[image]

---

Edit:
On the [original cable schematic](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/assets/9/e/f/8/2/951-00273-01_20180607_suzyqable_SCH_1.pdf) it looks like A8 and B8 is reversed?
[image]

---

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: You might need to connect all of the ground pins (A1, A12, B1, B12)

Comment: The instructions say to connect A4, A9, B4 & B9 to your cable's VBUS, but you've only connected A4. As a result your resistors are not connected to your cable's VBUS either.

Comment: I have tried this as well (the pictures doesn't reflect this), but the contacts are also internally connected on the device port, so it might be not necessary.

Comment: The A5 to VBUS resistor is supposed to be 22k. I can't tell what you're used, but I don't see the 2 red stripes I would expect to see for a 22k resistor.

Comment: You also need to swap D+ and D- back - what you show in your pics doesn't match the instructions.

Comment: I added new pictures to reflect the suggested changes.

Comment: I cleaned and re-soldered the USB C breakout three times now, also tried different USB A cables. Also flipped the board on the device port, but no response from the cable. Maybe a problem with the breakout board?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the problem, this breakout board is available as 'Male' and 'Female' version, the pcb silkscreen is intended for the socket version (female) so the plug version (male) is basically reversed.

[image]

The correct pinout for this specific breakout board is:

- A5: D+
- B5: D-
- A8: 22K resistor to VCC
- B8: 56K resistor to VCC

A fully working cable only needs the two resistors and the USB plug cable, additional joints for VCC/GND are not needed (at least on my device).

[image]
[image]